# In Swift, how to set a function's return value in a closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I am now making a UITextField with AutoComplete that users will get a place name and zip code list after they have tapped one or some letters.

I got an Autocomplelt (https://github.com/cjcoax/Autocomplete) and there is a delegate function:

`func autoCompleteItemsForSearchTerm(term: String) -> [AutocompletableOption]`

I have to send a http request with `term` to server and wait for a json response as `return`.

For network connenction, I used Moya lib and its Method like:
`CredentialProvider.request(.Autocomplete(term, 10)) { (result) -> () in    }`

Now, my question is: How can I make a return value after getting the response from server?

Thanks

Comment: Use completion block

Comment: You can use a dispatch group and a dispatch group wait but this will block the main thread and give a poor user experience. You will need to refactor the library so that the completion list can be delivered asynchronously or find a different library or write your own code

Comment: Using RxSwift can be a better approach  [add an event on your request .onNext: get json & do your stuff] https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

Comment: Look this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39567367/3108877) to set a function's return value in a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function with completion block:

```
class func authenticateUser(userName:String?,password:String?,completionHandler: (response:NSDictionary?) -> (Void)) ->Void
{
      completionHandler(response: nil(or)dict)
}
```

Call a function :

```
authenticateUser(emailId, password: password, completionHandler: { (response) in
      print(response)
})
```